# Why is the number of spark streaming tasks different from the Kafka partition?

Tags: spark-streaming

There are multiple topics in my Kafka but they all have only one partition. Spark streaming consumes these data through direct. In theory, shouldn't the number of tasks be the same as the number of partitions in Kafka? Why do I see so many tasks on spark ui？
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfqD9.png)

```
val data = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, PreferConsistent, SubscribePattern[String, String](data_pattern, kafkaParams))
val windows = 300
val newData = data.map(_.value()).filter(_.contains("id")).window(Seconds(windows), Seconds(windows))
handleData(newData)
```

Comment: What is `handleData` doing?

Comment: handlerData is a method of processing data